# UWSGI adding double slash to admin login form in Django

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, mezzanine

Running Django behind UWSGI, I have set up an instance of Mezzanine that is *almost* working perfectly.  The only problem is the admin login page does not work properly.  If you just try to log in normally than the browser is redirected to `http://admin/`.  The html form action attribute is set to `//admin/` instead of `/admin/` so the browser sees "admin" as being a domain name instead of a root directory of the current domain.

I've tried wading through the Django and Mezzanine package codes, but I can't see anything in there that should be causing an extraneous slash.  I found one web page saying that changing `settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` to `"/"` could cause this, but I am not overriding the default value of `None` so this shouldn't be the cause.

In urls.py I have the following (which I think is the default):

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",

    # Change the admin prefix here to use an alternate URL for the
    # admin interface, which would be marginally more secure.
    ("^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),

  ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time I've figured out what the problem is! I had followed some directions on how to set up uwsgi with nginx that said to include a line saying `uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /;`.  The purpose of `SCRIPT_NAME` is to provide the base path for the UWSGI application, so in this case it serves to double the slashes. I found the same problem occurring in pyramid. I suspect this will occur with any UWSGI application.

Comment: In general, you want to get your Django applications debugged locally, which would have changed the nature of your initial question  to one about *deploying* Django and Mezzanine rather than one about *installing*. Mezzanine's deployment documentation is excellent and the included Fabric script is a great place to start. http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html

Comment: @ken Your edit is really weird. While agree on your grammar fixes I strongly disagree on changing and/or adding entire sentences. If you want to *add* something to an answer you should write your own and not hijack the answers of others.

Comment: @bikeshedder, respectfully, I disagree. Editing answers for clarity is a crucial part of SO, and I have never seen complaints about it before. I removed some colloquialisms and added the explanation of SCRIPT_NAME, then finished the OPs thoughts on seeing this behavior in other uWSGI apps. That is hardly "hijacking". Besides, Tim Tisdall will get more karma for this, not me.

Comment: It does not matter who gets the reputation points. It is simply rude to write under false name. If you really want to edit the answer and add extra insight then mark it as such. e.g. "Note from ken:" but to be honest - this is exactly what the comments are for. If you want to add something to an answer use the comments.

Comment: yeah.. it's a little strange to add sentences in the first person as an edit. Especially when you add your own comment afterwards.